# Unable to RDP into windows server on GCE : No remote desktop license servers available

Tags: google-compute-engine, rdp, windows-server

I have windows server machine on GCE.Whenever I try to take remote or RDP into  machine it is showing

*The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote Desktop License Servers available to provide a license.
Please contact the server administrator*

I have reset the machine but didn't work. The solutions that I got on the net needs access to the machine first, but I am not able to access the machine. Here is a link http://www.dell.com/support/Article/us/en/04/635765/EN to troubleshoot this, but I am not able to access machine as the machine is on google server.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was just a tick in the Microsoft Remote Desktop client "Connect to an admin session"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my case license has been expired. But I was able to take remote in admin mode. Use the command in Run to take remote in admin mode

```
mstsc /admin
```

Then I added new license to continue remote service. For more detail on remote desktop licensing check out the link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732684.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This problem made by some kind of caching of remote desktop licensing in clients you can solve this by remove the bellow key in registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing
```

It's much easier to make a reg file and run it so .

1. Make a empty text file
2. Name it "mypatch.reg" or "mypatch.reg"
3. Put bellow text in it and save it

   ```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing]
   ```
4. Run it by dubble click on file!

It should remove the key.

Comment: https://support.hostway.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000636664-Windows-RDP-No-Remote-Desktop-License-Servers-available-Error-message-fix

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://www.stopdoingitwrong.co.uk/server-2012-rds-there-are-no-remote-desktop-license-servers/) the solution is to delete the following key     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\RCM\GracePeriod

I Followed Sunil Garg's instructions:

```
mstsc /admin
```

to remote into the server.

Then I deleted the key. Please note you must run regedit as System user to delete the key. Use the [RunAsSystem](http://www.qwertylab.com/download/runassystem.zip) tool to achieve this